# combining 2 if statements

Tags: php

I have 2 if statements I want to combine into one.

These are the current if statements:

```
if (empty($_POST['route']))
{
    $formerrors[] = '<span class="error">route</span>';
} else {
    $route = escape_data($_POST['route']);

}


if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    $formerrors[] = '<span class="error">route</span>';
} else {
    $route = escape_data($_POST['route']);

}
```

i need something like:

```
if (empty($_POST['route'])) & (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    $formerrors[] = '<span class="error">route</span>';
} else {
    $route = escape_data($_POST['route']);

}
```

but not 100% sure how to achieve this

Comment: `&&` is the separator to use here, or the word `AND`

Comment: The answer was already given. But also, remember to give a go to your chosen language's documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which meaning you actually want: change `&` to `&&` ("and") or `||` ("or")`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: `||` is the right choice for the OPs question here.

Comment: thank you all, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php is what i was looking for on this one

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `||` (logical OR) here:

```
if ( empty($_POST['route']) || mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  ...
}
```

... otherwise your error processing code will be invoked only if BOTH `$_POST['route']` and `$result` are empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (empty($_POST['route']) ||  mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    $formerrors[] = '<span class="error">route</span>';
} else {
    $route = escape_data($_POST['route']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the Operators in PHP. You used `&` which is actually bitwise `and` operator, not the real `and`.

Answer (score 1):

dont know how to thank you all but http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php is what i was after.

Thanks all, this has given me something to read and also ill take into consideration all your comments

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it.

```
if ((empty($_POST['route'])) && (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0))
{
    $formerrors[] = '<span class="error">route</span>';
} else {
    $route = escape_data($_POST['route']);
}
```

Comment: need to replace && => ||

Comment: Yes, that would be necessary if he wants to check one or the other. But the code is correct if he wants the code to fire if both statements are true.

Comment: You have one more parenthesis in the first line...

Comment: That should not be a problem Steve. It's good practice to encapsulate boolean expressions in parenthesis to increase readability and emphasize separation :) You may also write it as (empty($var) == true)